# View database info of other instance installed on the local computer

Tags: sql-server

This is my problem: I have a local server with 2 SQL instances. How can I get info from a table in the other instance (while I'm connected to the first instance)? I believe this is possible but then this database is only read-only.

Thanks in advance!
a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to view the table using SQL Server Management Studio then just open up another connection in object explorer and enter the details for the other instance.

If you need to access the information via TSQL on the first instance (if you're doing cross database joins for example) then you'll likely need to explore linked servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Openrowset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).